# Need to add a no-arg constructor. Confused on what that is as well

Tags: java

I need to add a no-arg constructor right now I have my class and a driver program. I assume I put the constructor in the class along with the others but not sure how to do that. I need the no-arg constructor to default to 2 scoops of vanilla with all the standard toppings.
here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sundae
{
    public static final double TAX = 0.08625;
    private String icecream;
    private int scoops;
    private double scoopCost;
    private String toppings;
    private String allChoices;
    private String deluxeToppings;
    private int counter = 0;
    private double costOfDeluxeToppings = 0;
    private double costOfSundae = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public String iceCreamFlavor()
    {
        System.out.println("1. vanilla | 2. peanut butter | 3. chocolate "
                + "| 4. mint chocolate chip |\n  5. coffee | 6. strawberry | 7. raspberry "
                + "| 8. knickerbocker glory | 9. cookies and creme");
        int flavor = input.nextInt();
        switch(flavor)
        {
        case 1:
            icecream = "vanilla";
            break;
        case 2:
            icecream = "peanut butter";
            break;
        case 3:
            icecream = "chocolate";
            break;
        case 4:
            icecream = "mint chocolate chip";
            break;
        case 5:
            icecream = "coffe";
            break;
        case 6:
            icecream = "strawberry";
            break;
        case 7:
            icecream = "raspberry";
            break;
        case 8:
            icecream = "knickerbocker glory";
            break;
        case 9:
            icecream = "cookies and cream";
            break;
        default:
            icecream = "vanilla";
        }
        return icecream;
    }

    public int numberOfScoops()
    {
        scoops = input.nextInt();
        switch(scoops)
        {
        case 1:
            scoops = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            scoops = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
            scoops = 3;
            break;
        case 4:
            scoops = 4;
            break;
        case 5:
            scoops = 5;
            break;
        case 6:
            scoops = 6;
            break;
        default:
            scoops = 2;
        }
        return scoops;
    }

    public double costForScoops()
    {
        switch(scoops)
        {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("1 scoop cost $1.79");
            scoopCost = 1.79;
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("2 scoops cost $2.79");
            scoopCost = 2.79;
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("3 scoops cost $3.79");
            scoopCost = 3.79;
            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println("4 scoops cost $4.79");
            scoopCost = 4.79;
            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println("5 scoops cost $5.79");
            scoopCost = 5.79;
            break;

        case 6:
            System.out.println("6 scoops cost $6.79");
            scoopCost = 6.79;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("2 scoops cost $2.79");
            scoopCost = 2.79;
            break;
        }
        return scoopCost;
    }

    public String standardToppingList()
    {
        System.out.println("1. whipped cream | 2. syrup | 3. chocolate sprinkes "
                + "| 4. rainbow sprinkes | 5. cherry");
        String choice1 = "";
        String choice2 = "";
        String choice3 = "";
        String choice4 = "";
        String choice5 = "";

        int choice = 0;
        while(choice != -1)
        {
            choice = input.nextInt();
            switch(choice)
            {
            case 1:
                choice1 = "whipped cream, ";
                System.out.println(choice1);
                break;

            case 2:
                choice2 = "syrup, ";
                System.out.println(choice2);
                break;

            case 3:
                choice3 = "choclate sprinkles, ";
                System.out.println(choice3);
                break;

            case 4:
                choice4 = "rainbow sprinkles, ";
                System.out.println(choice4);
                break;

            case 5:
                choice5 = "cherry, ";
                System.out.println(choice5);
                break;

            case -1:
                break;

            default:
                choice = -1;
                choice1 = "whipped cream, ";
                choice2 = "syrup, ";
                choice3 = "choclate sprinkles, ";
                choice4 = "rainbow sprinkles, ";
                choice5 = "cherry, ";
                break;
            }
        }
        toppings = choice1 + choice2 + choice3 + choice4 + choice5;
        System.out.println("Your choices of toppings are: " + toppings);
        return toppings;
    }

    public String freeSyrupChoice()
    {
        System.out.println("1. hot fudge | 2. chocolate | 3. caramel | 4. strawberry");
        int choice = 0;
        String choice1 = "";
        String choice2 = "";
        String choice3 = "";
        String choice4 = "";
        while(choice != -1)
        {
            choice = input.nextInt();
            switch(choice)
            {
            case 1:
                choice1 = "hot fudge, ";
                System.out.println(choice1);
                break;

            case 2:
                choice2 = "chocolate, ";
                System.out.println(choice2);
                break;

            case 3:
                choice3 = "caramel, ";
                System.out.println(choice3);
                break;

            case 4:
                choice4 = "strawberry, ";
                System.out.println(choice4);
                break;

            case -1:
                break;

            default:
                choice = -1;
                choice1 = "hot fudge, ";
                break;
            }
        }
        allChoices = choice1 + choice2 + choice3 + choice4;
        System.out.println("Your choices of syrup include " + allChoices);
        return allChoices;
    }

    public String deluxeToppingList()
    {
        System.out.println("1. M&Ms | 2. Crushed Oreos | 3. Reeses | 4. Brownie Crunchies"
                + " | 5. Brownie Crunchies | 6. Kit Kats \n| 7. Marshmallow | 8. Granola clusters"
                + " | 9. Peanuts | 10. Walnuts");
        String choice1 = "";
        String choice2 = "";
        String choice3 = "";
        String choice4 = "";
        String choice5 = "";
        String choice6 = "";
        String choice7 = "";
        String choice8 = "";
        int choice = 0;
        while(choice != -1)
        {
            choice = input.nextInt();
            switch(choice)
            {
            case 1:
                choice1 = "M&M's, ";
                System.out.println(choice1);
                counter++;
                break;

            case 2:
                choice2 = "Crushed Oreos, ";
                System.out.println(choice2);
                counter++;
                break;



            case 3:
                choice3 = "Reeses, ";
                System.out.println(choice3);
                counter++;
                break;

            case 4:
                choice4 = "Brownie Crunchies, ";
                System.out.println(choice4);
                counter++;
                break;

            case 5:
                choice5 = "Kit Kats, ";
                System.out.println(choice5);
                counter++;
                break;

            case 6:
                choice6 = "Granola Clusters, ";
                System.out.println(choice6);
                counter++;
                break;

            case 7:
                choice7 = "Peanuts, ";
                System.out.println(choice7);
                counter++;
                break;

            case 8:
                choice8 = "Walnuts, ";
                System.out.println(choice8);
                counter++;
                break;
            case -1:
                break;

            default:
                choice = -1;
                break;

            }
        }
        deluxeToppings = choice1 + choice2 + choice3 + choice4 + choice5 + choice6 + choice7 + choice8;
        System.out.println("Your choices of deluxe toppings are: " + deluxeToppings);
        return deluxeToppings;
    }

    public int counterD()
    {
        System.out.println("You got " + counter + " deluxe toppings");
        return counter;
    }

    public double costOfDeluxeToppings()
    {
        costOfDeluxeToppings =  counter * 1.25;
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s" , "Each deluxe topping cost $1.25 each ",
        costOfDeluxeToppings, " will be added to your total.");
        return costOfDeluxeToppings;
    }

    public double costOfSundae()
    {
        costOfSundae = scoopCost + costOfDeluxeToppings;
        return costOfSundae;
    }

    public void outputOrder()
    {
        System.out.println("Your order consists of " + scoops + " scoop/s of " + icecream +
                " icecream with " + toppings + allChoices + deluxeToppings);
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f\n" , "Your sub-total is: $" , costOfSundae);
        double tax = costOfSundae * TAX;
        System.out.println("+ 8.625%");
        double total = costOfSundae + tax;
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f" , "Your total is: $" , total);

    }
}
```

Comment: `public Sundae() { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Oh, wow... Switch cases really unnecessary in most of those methods

Comment: Read along. Talks about no argument constructor.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: @cricket_007 didnt know how else to go to a default. What else would you recommend?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch what goes in the block?

Comment: Take the scoops method, for example. All of them return the input number. Use an if statement to check invalid values, and then return the default value. Otherwise, just return `scoops`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need the no-arg constructor to default to 2 scoops of vanilla with all the standard toppings.

```
public Sundae() {
    this.icecream = "vanilla" ;
    this.scoops = 2;
    this.toppings = "list, of, all, standard, toppings" ; 
}
```

I would like to point out that you likely can minimize your number of member variables.

For example

```
public double costOfSundae()
{
    costOfSundae = scoopCost + costOfDeluxeToppings;
    return costOfSundae;
}
```

Can simply be

```
public double costOfSundae()
{
    return scoopCost + costOfDeluxeToppings;
}
```